# Call method from external .js file in Node.JS

Tags: javascript, node.js

I created a file `db.js` that connect to the Oracle database.

```
process.env.ORA_SDTZ = 'UTC';
var oracledb = require('oracledb');
exports.saveInDB = async function(data) {
  let connection;

  try {
    let sql, binds, options, result;
    binds = [];

    connection = await oracledb.getConnection({
      user: "user",
      password: "pass",
      connectString: "localhost/dbname"
    });

    var start = new Date();

    for (var i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
      sql = `INSERT INTO mytab VALUES (:1, :2, :3)`;
      binds = [
        [i, "Inserted row number => " + i + " =>" + data, 0]
      ];
      options = {
        autoCommit: true,
        bindDefs: [
          { type: oracledb.NUMBER },
          { type: oracledb.STRING, maxSize: 999 },
          { type: oracledb.NUMBER }
        ]
      };
      result = await connection.executeMany(sql, binds, options);

      console.log("Inserted row number => ", i);
    }

    var end = new Date() - start;
    console.info('Execution time: %dms', end);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  } finally {
    if (connection) {
      try {
        await connection.close();
      } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

When I want to call `var db = require('./db.js'); db.saveInDb(data);`, This error occurred : `TypeError: db.saveInDb is not a function`.
I try the other format to define the method like `async function saveInDb(data)` but the result not changes.
How can I fix this error?
I search for this but can not fix this.
Thanks.

Comment: @ShubhDixit Yes, I do that in line 3 : `exports.saveInDB = async function(data)`. I try some other format to exports.

Comment: Actually, I can't find any problem with your code. I've executed after solving the problem of the additional curly bracket and it works correctly. Maybe there's a problem in the part you're not showing that causes the error. Could you edit the question with those information?

Comment: @oniramarf I edit the code. when just run db.js, everything is ok, but when calling in main.js the errors occurred.

Comment: I have tested it again and can't find any error about `saveInDb is not a function`. Could you please add your project directories? Maybe you're importing **another** `db.js` which doesn't have that function.

Comment: @oniramarf i call the method in this way: `var db = require('./db.js');db.saveInDb(data);`

Comment: Is the file where you do that in the same directory of the db.js you're trying to call? Or they are in different directories?

Comment: @oniramarf Yes, they are at same directory.

Comment: I have tested exactly that and I don't get any error. Your code works perfectly on my environment. Maybe adding your environment information (OS/node version/etc..) could help solve the issue.

Comment: @oniramarf how do you call the `saveInDb(data)` in `main.js`?

Comment: @oniramarf My node version is v10.15.3 and my OS is Windows7 64bit.

Comment: @iMohammadi.ir Simplify your code. Start by defining a simple async function that uses setTimeout. Get that working and move on from there. This series has several examples of exporting and importing such functions: https://jsao.io/2018/03/creating-a-rest-api-with-node-js-and-oracle-database/

Comment: I just spotted something else... You have: `exports.saveInDB = async function(data)` and then `var db = require('./db.js'); db.saveInDb(data);`. The export has a capital `B` in `DB` but you're invoking it with a lowercase `b`.

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
export const saveInDB = async function(data) {
            let connection;
            try {
    // my codes....
                }
                var end = new Date() - start;
                console.info('Execution time: %dms', end);
            } catch (err) {
                console.error(err);
            } finally {
                if (connection) {
                    try {
                        await connection.close();
                    } catch (err) {
                        console.error(err);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: I call the function: `var db = require('./db.js'); db.saveInDb(data);` but error occurred : `SyntaxError: Unexpected token export`

Answer (score 0):

```js
    process.env.ORA_SDTZ = 'UTC';
    var oracledb = require('oracledb');
    const saveInDB = async function(data) {
        let connection;
        try {
// my codes....
            }
            var end = new Date() - start;
            console.info('Execution time: %dms', end);
        } catch (err) {
            console.error(err);
        } finally {
            if (connection) {
                try {
                    await connection.close();
                } catch (err) {
                    console.error(err);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    export { saveInDB }
```

Comment: This error occurred : `export { saveInDB }
^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token export`

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your approach is that `async function(){` returns a `Promise` which you are trying to call as a function in `var db = require('./db.js'); db.saveInDb(data);`, Hence the error.
Execute the promise appropriately(depends what's in the db.js file) and this can be resolved.

Comment: The keywords `async function` create an AsyncFunction. When invoked, such functions return promises. But exporting an AsyncFunction should be fine.

Comment: Yeah, it should be. But the OP isn't handling it like a promise. He's trying to call it as a function without resolving it.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow - he doesn't need to resolve anything. Do you mean that he's invoking it without using then/catch? If so, I agree, he should. However, he shouldn't be getting the error he is for that problem.